How to turn off error highlighting in powerline (doomemacs)

As you can see there is a wavy lines under 11, x, 0, !, 1 in emacs powerline.
Is it bug or feature?
I use doomemacs:
GNU Emacs     v29.2            nil
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre       HEAD -> master c8a5e6ec1 2024-09-17 17:30:57 -0400
Doom modules  v24.10.0-pre     HEAD -> master c8a5e6ec1 2024-09-17 17:30:57 -0400

